# SQL statement works with "IN" but when trying to get opposite (inversed) result with "NOT IN" it outputs everything

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-in

I'm trying to output all students that have no grades in 'NSA programming'.
This same query with 'IN' instead of 'NOT IN' works perfectly for students that do have a grade in 'NSA programming' lecture,

but when I try to inverse it with 'NOT IN' query outputs all students and now just those that don't have a grade in this lecture.

```
SELECT oc_students.name, oc_students.last_name
FROM oc_students 
INNER JOIN oc_grades ON oc_students.id_students=oc_grades.id_students 
    WHERE oc_grades.id_lecture
    NOT IN (SELECT oc_lecturesid_lecture FROM oc_lectures WHERE lecture_name='NSA programming');
```

Not sure if my understanding of 'NOT IN' and 'IN' is wrong but from what I can tell this should be working as intended since I'm just reversing 'IN' statement.

If someone could tell me  why this is not working and maybe show me the correct way  of doing it that would be awesome.

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question. I removed the database tags as it is unclear which one you are actually using. Please add the tag of *only* the database you are actually using

Comment: Watch out for null values from the sub-query! (I usually recommend `NOT EXISTS` instead of `NOT IN`.)

Comment: Are you sure inverting `IN`/`NOT IN` is actually inverting your query? Might *all* of your students have attended *at least one* lecture that wasn't `NSA Programming`?

Comment: sorry for wrong tags, corrected it. I have no null values in my database.

@Damien_The_Unbeliever yes that is correct. students also have grades in other lectures. From my understanding 'NOT IN' works in such way that if student doesn't have that particular grade in 'NSA Programming' it would output him even if he has grades elsewhere?

Comment: you should use left join with not null

Comment: Seems like what you should be doing is an outer join between students and grades in lecture NSA programming, and then select the students with NULL grades.

Comment: What your queries do is this: **IN:** Give me all students, each as often as they have a grade in NSA programming. **NOT IN:** Give me all students, each as often as they have a grade in a subject different from NSA programming. (As your subquery returns the one ID for the NSA programming lecture, you could just as well use `=` instead of `IN` and `<>` instead of `NOT IN`.)

Answer (score 2):

Don't join, when you only want to select certain students. Put your conditions in the `WHERE` clause where they belong.

**Students with grades in NSA programming:**

```
SELECT name, last_name
FROM oc_students
WHERE id_students IN
(
  SELECT id_students
  FROM oc_grades
  WHERE id_lecture =
          (SELECT id_lecture FROM oc_lectures WHERE lecture_name = 'NSA programming')
);
```

**Students with no grade in NSA programming:**

```
SELECT name, last_name
FROM oc_students
WHERE id_students NOT IN
(
  SELECT id_students
  FROM oc_grades
  WHERE id_lecture =
          (SELECT id_lecture FROM oc_lectures WHERE lecture_name = 'NSA programming')
);
```